# ¿Cómo hacer el efecto de texto que se escribe palabra a palabra en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando una función que tome como argumento una cadena, la convierta a lista y la imprima dentro de un for en la misma linea con un `sleep()` para simular la escritura del texto.

```
import time 

def mecanografiar_texto(texto_a_mecanografiar):
    """La funcion recibe un  argumento , el texto que quieras mecanografiar(que  debe ser una cadena)"""

    texto_a_mecanografiar_convertido_a_lista = texto_a_mecanografiar.split()
    for palabra in texto_a_mecanografiar_convertido_a_lista:
        print(palabra, end=" ")
        time.sleep(.4)

print("")
mecanografiar_texto ("texto a probar ")
```

El problema es que no lo imprime palabra por palabra, espera a que transcurra el tiempo y luego imprime en pantalla toda la lista.

Puedo hacer el efecto palabra por palabra solo con `print()` y `sleep()`, pero para un texto grande es tedioso y dificulta la lectura del código.

¿Qué debo modificar a mi código para que lo imprima palabra a palabra?

Comment: hola quisiera ayudarte, pero aun no domino python, sin embargo respondi a tu problema pero en js, revisalo y espero que te ayude http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46823/hacer-el-efecto-de-un-texto-que-se-est%C3%A1-escribiendo-por-si-solo/46840#46840

Comment: Muchas gracias @x-rw , pero no se mucho de Javascript y quiero  hacerlo  por una CLI (actualmente lo estoy haciendo desde la terminal de Debian) ,pero ese es el efecto que quiero lograr , de nuevo gracias por responder

Comment: pero ya funciona verdad, solo tienes problemas para texto largos?

Comment: Si, pero solo implementadolo asi : 
`print("hola") 
sleep(.4)
print("Mundo")
`

Comment: deberia ser letra por letra?

Comment: quiero pasarle una cadena a la función , funciona bien para convertir la cadena a lista ,pero  luego que quiero iterar la lista para imprimir el valor y  esperar mediante el sleep no lo hace de la forma que quiero , lo que hace es esperar a que pase el tiempo por cada iterracción y despues de que itera todo imprime toda la lista (esto ultimo lo supongo por el tiempo que pasa)

Comment: probe tu codigo y funciona palabra por palabra, y no como dices todo en uno, probalo en linea aca el link https://repl.it/FcxH

Comment: Es raro , probé en python3 tanto en windows como en debian y no me funciona asi , me lo imprime todo en uno,gracias por probarlo

Comment: no se que decir, no es problema de codigo, es otro el problema, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Lo estoy probando desde debian en  python 3.4.2 y en windows en python 3.6.0 , no se si sea la instalación , muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: de nada, me alegro haberte ayudado !!! y bienvenido a la comunidad

Comment: Ya encontre el problema, ocurre al parecer por compatibilidad entre print() y sleep(), se usa stdout.write y asi si se hace el efecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tratar de resolver mi duda , Gracias a todos !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion *sleep()* presenta problemas con la funcion *print()* cuando se hace la escritura a la salida estandar. Posteriormente realizar un *flush()* de la misma.

En ese caso te recomiendo que uses la funcion *write()*, que pertenece a la libreria *sys*.

He aqui el ejemplo:

```
import time
import sys

def mecanografiar(texto):

 lista = texto.split()

 for palabra in lista:
    sys.stdout.write(palabra + " ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(4)

print("\n")
mecanografiar("Hola mundo Python Rules!")
print("\n")
```

PD: He modificado los nombres de las variables, para hacerlo mas legible a la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias , si me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
from time import sleep

def mecanografiar(texto):
    for palabras in texto.split():
        sleep(0.1)
        print(palabras, end=' ', flush=True)
```

Comment: Su pregunta se encuentra en la lista de publicaciones de baja calidad (debido a su contenido) .Por favor agrega una descripción a este código.

Answer (score 0):

Imprime por consola el texto caracter a caracter:

```
import time,sys

    Message=" este es el texto que se escribe palabra a palabra en Python"

    for i in Message:
      sys.stdout.flush()
      print(i,end="")
      time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Gracias por tu aporte aunque no responde a la pregunta, que pide palabra por palabra.