# Realizar efecto máquina de escribir con pausa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy creando una web y necesito hacer que un texto:

1. Se escriba con un efecto como de máquina de escribir.
2. Cuando ya termine de escribir debe permanecer el texto escrito por unos tres segundos.
3. Y por último debe desaparecer el texto y volver a escribirse con el efecto de máquina de escribir y así sucesivamente.

El efecto ya tengo hecho con JavaScript y ya logré que se repita pero lo hace inmediatamente sin hacer la pausa de 3 segundos. Si alguien me puede ayudar, ¿qué es lo que me falta?.

El código que tengo es:

```js
$(function(){

    var texto = "Texto Ejemplo / Ejemplo 2  / Ejemplo 3";
    maquina("typer",texto,100);

});


function maquina(contenedor,texto,intervalo){
   // Calculamos la longitud del texto
   longitud = texto.length;
   // Obtenemos referencia del div donde se va a alojar el texto.
   tagHtml = document.getElementById(contenedor);
   tagHtml.innerHTML="";
   var i=0;
   // Creamos el timer
   timer = setInterval(function(){
      // Vamos añadiendo letra por letra y la _ al final.
      tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,tagHtml.innerHTML.length-1) + texto.charAt(i) + "_";
      // Si hemos llegado al final del texto..
      if(i >= longitud){
         // Salimos del Timer y quitamos la barra baja (_)
         clearInterval(timer);
         tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,longitud);

         maquina("typer",texto,100);
         return true;
      } else {
         // En caso contrario.. seguimos
         i++;
      }
   },intervalo);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p id="typer"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: aqui tienes la solucion http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46823/hacer-el-efecto-de-un-texto-que-se-est%C3%A1-escribiendo-por-si-solo/46840#46840

Comment: Sabes que eso ya tengo hecho , esta casi igual , el problema es que el texto luego de  haberse mostrado debe permanecer visible por unos segundos y de ahí debe borrarse y comenzar el efecto desde el inicio, esa parte no lo logro. Gracias con todo si puedes ayudarme con lo que me falta muchas gracias

Comment: disculpa como hiciste para solucionar el tema de la pausa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con el método `setTimeout` del objecto window, haz la siguiente modificación:

```js
$(function(){
 var texto = "Texto Ejemplo / Ejemplo 2  / Ejemplo 3";
 maquina("typer",texto,100,0);
});

function maquina(contenedor,texto,intervalo,n){
 var i=0,
  // Creamos el timer
  timer = setInterval(function() {
  if ( i<texto.length ) {
   // Si NO hemos llegado al final del texto..
   // Vamos añadiendo letra por letra y la _ al final.
   $("#"+contenedor).html(texto.substr(0,i++) + "_");
  } else {
   // En caso contrario..
   // Salimos del Timer y quitamos la barra baja (_)
   clearInterval(timer);
   $("#"+contenedor).html(texto);
   // Auto invocamos la rutina n veces (0 para infinito)
   if ( --n!=0 ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     maquina(contenedor,texto,intervalo,n);
    },3600);
   }
  }
 },intervalo);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <p id="typer"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Excelente , ahí si me funciono de lujo, muchas gracias por la ayuda , quedo genial. :)

Comment: pregunta como haces que se ejecute lo que pones, aun no he descubierto como hacerlo :P gracias

Answer (score 2):

perdon no me di cuenta creo que funcionaria añadiendo un timeout en esta parte

```
function maquina(contenedor,texto,intervalo){
   // Calculamos la longitud del texto
   longitud = texto.length;
   // Obtenemos referencia del div donde se va a alojar el texto.
   tagHtml = document.getElementById(contenedor);
   tagHtml.innerHTML="";
   var i=0;
   // Creamos el timer
   timer = setInterval(function(){
      // Vamos añadiendo letra por letra y la _ al final.
      tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,tagHtml.innerHTML.length-1) + texto.charAt(i) + "_";
      // Si hemos llegado al final del texto..
      if(i >= longitud){
         // Salimos del Timer y quitamos la barra baja (_)
         clearInterval(timer);
         tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,longitud);
         setTimeOut(function(){
            maquina("typer",texto,100);
            return true;
         }, 5000);
      } else {
         // En caso contrario.. seguimos
         i++;
      }
   },intervalo);
};
```

esto hará que se llame la funcion maquina despues de 5 segundos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta si efectivamente eso faltaba , ya me ayudaron anteriormente y se soluciono , me faltaba un poco para logralo jeje

Answer (score 0):

Hola barckl3y recuerda que el setInterval y el SetTimeOut funcionan con milisegundos por lo que si queremos que una accion se realice en 1 segundo debemos indicarlo en milisegundos osea 1000 en tu caso estas poniendo el intervalo 100 milisegundos que es casi nada solo cambialo y funcionara

```
    $(function(){

    var texto = "Texto Ejemplo / Ejemplo 2  / Ejemplo 3";
    maquina("typer",texto,3000);

});


function maquina(contenedor,texto,intervalo){
   // Calculamos la longitud del texto
   longitud = texto.length;
   // Obtenemos referencia del div donde se va a alojar el texto.
   tagHtml = document.getElementById(contenedor);
   tagHtml.innerHTML="";
   var i=0;
   // Creamos el timer
   timer = setInterval(function(){
      // Vamos añadiendo letra por letra y la _ al final.
      tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,tagHtml.innerHTML.length-1) + texto.charAt(i) + "_";
      // Si hemos llegado al final del texto..
      if(i >= longitud){
         // Salimos del Timer y quitamos la barra baja (_)
         clearInterval(timer);
         tagHtml.innerHTML = tagHtml.innerHTML.substr(0,longitud);

         maquina("typer",texto,100);
         return true;
      } else {
         // En caso contrario.. seguimos
         i++;
      }
   },intervalo);
};
```

Comment: Gracias @a-serrano intente lo que me dijiste pero no funciona porque el tiempo que estamos ahí cambiando es el tiempo que se demora en el efecto de maquina de escribir , ahora necesito que después de que el texto ya salió con ese efecto , el texto se vea por unos 5 segundos mas sin hacer nada y de ahí debe borrarse el texto y empezar nuevamente el efecto. gracias con todo , espero que me puedas ayudar